# Appium - the value of the validation's label does not changed

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

Recently, I started to use the Appium for test automation of my application which is written with native script.

The problem is, in sign up section, the value of the validation's label does not change in the Appium/Selenium framework. here is the snapshot of two different text-field with valid and invalid data.

### valid data

[image]

### invalid data

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, what are you expecting to change?  It's a label, not a textbox.  ElementTypeStaticText implies to me that the text does not change, it's not an editable control.

Comment: @BillHileman. exactly. the value of this control changes in android ( empty first, and changes during the form validation process) but in iOS, the value of the labels is kind of fix in the inspector , but the display shows the validation error.

Comment: @Mironline - did you tried to reproduce this with any other inspector ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case Appium is out-of-sync with the device, consider clicking "Refresh Source & Screenshot" button in the Appium Desktop and Appium Server should obtain "fresh" sources and image from the device or simulator:

[image]

You can also consider using [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) as the alternative for the Appium Desktop, it makes the process of managing devices and emulators/simulators much easier, especially when it comes to [managing provisioning profiles and certificates for real iOS devices](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/)

Comment: I don't think so, I've refreshed the page several times but the value did not change.

Comment: It might be the case that the value has been stored in cache after first edit and is being reflected afterwards. Did you try uninstalling and installing the app again?

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by accessibility labels in Xcode. I hade the same problem in my project at work but after removing the hard coded labels, I was able to get the values I expected from Appium.

The accessibility properties can be found in the Storyboard or nib under the 'Identity Inspector'